# jQuery UI datepicker mm/dd/y format year 1915 converted to 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a bug in my jquery ui datepicker. I have the format: mm/dd/y , and for example the year is: 1915. So, 7 February 1915 will be: 02/07/15. After I select this date and close the datepicker, I can see with Firebug Inspect that the year is well saved, it's 1915, but when I open the datepicker again, the year selected is 2015 and not 1915.

I'm using jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-ui-1.11.4.
I'm also using this library: https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide some example code of how you're using datepicker. If you're working with a date object versus a string, this should be fine. If you're working with a string, there is no way for JS to determine that this is 1915 versus 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem and the solution.

The problem was that somwhere in my code I used "setYear" function. According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear I found that:

```
For years greater than or equal to 2000, the value returned by getYear() is 100 or greater. For example, if the year is 2026, getYear() returns 126.
For years between and including 1900 and 1999, the value returned by getYear() is between 0 and 99. For example, if the year is 1976, getYear() returns 76.
For years less than 1900, the value returned by getYear() is less than 0. For example, if the year is 1800, getYear() returns -100.
```

This website also suggested the solution:

```
To take into account years before and after 2000, you should use getFullYear() instead of getYear() so that the year is specified in full.
```

Thanks for trying to help. I hope this will also help others in the future. **Don't use setYear** function, **use setFullYear** instead.